# Discord.py error discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This code:

```
    @commands.command(name="currency", aliases=['ce'])
    async def currencyexchange(self, ctx, currency1, currency2, amount:str):
        url = "https://www.amdoren.com/api/currency.php?api_key=WTkbre7JxKME95tsu62R2bBng42rKE&from=" + currency1 + "&to=" + currency2 + "&amount=" + amount
        async with ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get(url) as response:      
                r = await response.json(content_type=None)
                embed = discord.Embed(colour=discord.Colour.purple(), timestamp = ctx.message.created_at, title=f"Currency Rates")
                embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.author}")
                embed.add_field(name=f"Exchanged", value = f"{r('amount')}", inline = False)
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

returns the error shown the title. Not sure where I messed up, but I'm in need of some help.

API returns this:

```
{
"error" : 0,
"error_message" : "-",
"amount" : 6.31656
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

```
embed.add_field(name=f"Exchanged", value = f"{r('amount')}", inline = False)
```

When you write `r('amount')`, with parentheses it's treating `r` like a function. In order to get the value of the `amount` field from `r` you need to use square brackets. It would look like this:

```
embed.add_field(name=f"Exchanged", value = f"{r['amount']}", inline = False)
```